# Alter the masked value symbol - - when printing a masked Numpy array

Tags: numpy

I am looking for a way to alter the `--` masked value symbol when printing a masked Numpy array

Comment: Why? How do you want to represent masked values?

Comment: It's about aligning columns when printing.
I have a nxn array which represents a crossword board. Currently I have '1' representing 'black' and '0' representing white. This prints nicely. 
I am considering switching to a masked array. I would like to preserve column alignment and my initial thought was that ``---`` for masked values rather than ``--`` would allow this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poking around in the `np.ma` module, and the methods of a masked array I found

```
np.ma.masked_print_option
"Handle the string used to represent missing data in a masked array."
```

The default '--':

```
In [619]: np.ma.masked_print_option.display()
Out[619]: '--'
```

changed to 'xx'

```
In [620]: np.ma.masked_print_option.set_display('xx')

In [621]: M
Out[621]: 
masked_array(data = [0 xx 2 xx 4 xx 6 xx 8 xx],
             mask = [False  True False  True False  True False  True False  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
```