# Replacing masked values (--) with a Null or None value using fiil_value from ma numpy in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, astropy

Is there a way to replace a masked value in a numpy masked array as a null or None value? This is what I have tried but does not work.

```
for stars in range(length_masterlist_final):
    ....
    star = customSimbad.query_object(star_names[stars])
        #obtain stellar info.
        photometry_dataframe.iloc[stars,0] = star_IDs[stars]
        photometry_dataframe.iloc[stars,1] = star_names[stars]

        photometry_dataframe.iloc[stars,2] = star['FLUX_U'][0]
        #Replace "--" masked values with a Null (i.e., '') value.
        photometry_dataframe.iloc[stars,2] = ma.filled(photometry_dataframe.iloc[stars,2], fill_value=None)
.....
photometry_dataframe.to_csv(output_dir + "simbad_photometry.csv", index=False, header=True, na_rep='NaN')
```

specifically

```
(photometry_dataframe.iloc[stars,2] = ma.filled(photometry_dataframe.iloc[stars,2], fill_value=None))
```

produces

```
'MaskedConstant' object has no attribute '_fill_value'
```

I want to replace masked values '--' with '' when I output the dataframe as a csv file. One work around is to read the outputted csv file back into python and replace '--' with '', but this is a horrible solution. There must be a better solution. I don't want masked values printed as '--' in the csv file.

Comment: What exactly is `photometry_dataframe.iloc[stars,2]`.  The 1st argument of `filled` should be a numpy array, or better yet a `numpy` masked array.  The  error indicates that that is not the case.

Comment: **photometry_dataframe.iloc[stars,2]** is a pandas dataframe, initialized as:
**photometry_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(index=star_IDs, columns=column_names)**. From the looks of things, fill_value only accepts numerical values. For example, fill_value=0 replaces the masked values with 0. What I want is a null value, instead of '--'.

Comment: For `numpy` masked arrays, `'--'` isn't the fill.  It's the placeholder in the print string.  If the object is a `dataframe` then use `pandas` methods to format and/or fill it.

Comment: How exactly would I fill it using pandas? **print(type(photometry_dataframe))** says that the photometry_dataframe is a pandas dataframe **(pandas.core.frame.DataFrame)**. I did try for example **if photometry_dataframe.iloc[stars,2] == "--":
            photometry_dataframe.iloc[stars,2] = ""     #replace missing value indicator '--' with ''.** But this does not work.

Comment: I don't know if it will help with your mix of pandas and numpy masked arrays, but take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192741/alter-the-masked-value-symbol-when-printing-a-masked-numpy-array

Comment: Have you tried the `pandas` `fillna`?  There are a number SO questions about that method.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser your suggestion worked. Thank you!

Comment: You should thank @hpaulj by upvoting his answer there.

Comment: Actually it was your solution @WarrenWeckesser that worked. Can you post your solution as an answer so I can up vote it.

Comment: I didn't post a solution, I gave link to a solution by @hpaulj.  If that really solved your problem, you could delete this question (it is basically a duplicate) and upvote the solution at the link.

Answer (score 3):

Use Astropy:

```
>>> from pandas import DataFrame
>>> from astropy.table import Table
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> df = DataFrame()
>>> df['a'] = [1, np.nan, 2]
>>> df['b'] = [3, 4, np.nan]
>>> df
    a   b
0   1   3
1 NaN   4
2   2 NaN
>>> t = Table.from_pandas(df)
>>> t
<Table masked=True length=3>
   a       b   
float64 float64
------- -------
    1.0     3.0
     --     4.0
    2.0      --
>>> t.write('photometry.csv', format='ascii.csv')
>>> 
(astropy)neptune$ cat photometry.csv 
a,b
1.0,3.0
,4.0
2.0,
```

You can specify arbitrary transformations from table values to output values using the `fill_values` parameter (http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/ascii/write.html#parameters-for-write).

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. I got the following error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'MaskedConstant'

Comment: What version of Numpy are you using?

Comment: I'm using numpy version 1.10.2

Comment: And what version of astropy?

Comment: astropy version is 1.1.post2

Comment: Hmm.  Did you get the exception running the example I gave or using your own DataFrame?  In either case (but especially the former) I would be interested in seeing the full traceback.  Astropy io.ascii defines its own version of the `masked` constant which is guaranteed to be hashable, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I didn't get the exception running the example you gave me. Does it have something to do with initializing the dataframe as a pandas dataframe (i.e., **photometry_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(index=star_IDs, columns=column_names)**)? The exception is only thrown when trying to write the file out.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simbad_photometry_test.py", line 318, in <module>
    t.write(output_dir + "simbad_photometry_test.csv", format='ascii.csv')
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/table/table.py", line 2278, in write
    io_registry.write(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/io/registry.py", line 380, in write
    writer(data, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/io/ascii/connect.py", line 43, in io_write
    return write(table, filename, format=format, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/io/ascii/ui.py", line 675, in write
    writer.write(table, output)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/io/ascii/fastbasic.py", line 171, in write
    self._write(table, output, { 'fill_values': [(core.masked, '')] })

Comment: File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/io/ascii/fastbasic.py", line 149, in _write
    writer.write(output, header_output, output_types)
  File "astropy/io/ascii/cparser.pyx", line 996, in astropy.io.ascii.cparser.FastWriter.write (astropy/io/ascii/cparser.c:18642)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'MaskedConstant'

Comment: Can you try removing the line `photometry_dataframe.iloc[stars,2] = ma.filled(photometry_dataframe.iloc[stars,2], fill_value=None)`.    Also, to simplify things a bit try using `fast_writer=False` so it uses the pure-Python writer.  Finally, if there is any way you can reduce the problem to a code snippet that I can fully reproduce then it should be straightforward to understand the problem.