# Replace string 'Null' with pandas NaN - Vectorised

Tags: python, pandas

The last question that asked this was in 2016 and used the astropy package.

[Replacing masked values (--) with a Null or None value using fiil_value from ma numpy in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026040/replacing-masked-values-with-a-null-or-none-value-using-fiil-value-from-ma)

I was wondering if since then there is a faster, vectorised way, than using `applymap`:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x=='NULL' else x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) or [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), which by default change value to `NaN`s by condition:

```
df = df.replace('NULL', np.nan)
```

For compare mixed data use `values` or cast to `string`:

```
df = df.mask(df.values == 'NULL')
```

---

```
df = df.mask(df.astype(str) == 'NULL')
```

Comment: Mask doesn't work if my dataframe has a mix of ints and strings.
Also, replace would also effect cells that have xxNULLxx

Comment: i modify it a bit, can you check?

Comment: No, replace by default not replacing substrings.

Comment: Sweet, mask + astype(str) works as I wanted. Thanks! Ah, i thought replace also effected substrings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in-place:

```
df[df.astype(str)=='NULL'] = np.nan
```

Example:

```
>>> df
      a     b
0    10  NULL
1  NULL    20
>>> df[df=='NULL'] = np.nan
>>> df
     a    b
0   10  NaN
1  NaN   20
```